# select case getting item from a combo box not working

Tags: vb.net

The expected result is when i click the add button after selecting the homeroom, place and event it wont give me the message box and then when i click the display button it will put it into the selected homeroom and the score into the list box. but when i click add the message box apears and the array doesnt get filled. i think its a problem with the case selects not realising that the things are selected.

```
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1
    Dim Sting As String
    Dim score1 As Integer
    Dim score2 As Integer
    Dim score3 As Integer
    Dim score4 As Integer
    Dim score5 As Integer
    Dim score6 As Integer
    Dim score7 As Integer
    Dim score8 As Integer

    Dim intcounter1 As Integer = 0
    Dim points1(intcounter1) As Integer
    Dim intcounter2 As Integer = 0
    Dim points2(intcounter2) As Integer
    Dim intcounter3 As Integer = 0
    Dim points3(intcounter3) As Integer
    Dim intcounter4 As Integer = 0
    Dim points4(intcounter4) As Integer
    Dim intcounter5 As Integer = 0
    Dim points5(intcounter5) As Integer
    Dim intcounter6 As Integer = 0
    Dim points6(intcounter6) As Integer
    Dim intcounter7 As Integer = 0
    Dim points7(intcounter7) As Integer
    Dim intcounter8 As Integer = 0
    Dim points8(intcounter8) As Integer
    Dim place As Integer
    Dim reader As New XmlTextReader("score.txt")
    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("score.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.1")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.2")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.3")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.4")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.5")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.6")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.7")
        cmbHomeroom.Items.Add("7.8")

        cmbPlace.Items.Add("1")
        cmbPlace.Items.Add("2")
        cmbPlace.Items.Add("3")
        cmbPlace.Items.Add("4")
        cmbPlace.Items.Add("5")
        cmbPlace.Items.Add("over 5")

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If rdbB25.Checked Or rdbF25.Checked Then
            Select Case Sting
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "1"
                    place = 20
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "2"
                    place = 10
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "3"
                    place = 5
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "4"
                    place = 4
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "5"
                    place = 3
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "over 5"
                    place = 1
                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a Place")
            End Select
        End If
        If rdbB50.Checked Or rdbF50.Checked Then
            Select Case Sting
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "1"
                    place = 25
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "2"
                    place = 15
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "3"
                    place = 10
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "4"
                    place = 6
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "5"
                    place = 4
                Case cmbPlace.Text = "over 5"
                    place = 2
                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a Place")
            End Select
        End If



        Select Case Sting
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.1"
                points1(intcounter1) = place
                intcounter1 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.2"
                points2(intcounter2) = place
                intcounter2 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.3"
                points3(intcounter3) = place
                intcounter3 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.4"
                points4(intcounter4) = place
                intcounter4 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.5"
                points5(intcounter5) = place
                intcounter5 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.6"
                points6(intcounter6) = place
                intcounter6 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.7"
                points7(intcounter7) = place
                intcounter7 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case cmbHomeroom.Text = "7.8"
                points8(intcounter8) = place
                intcounter8 = intcounter1 + 1
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a homeroom")
        End Select


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click


        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Homerooms:   Points:")
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("7.1            " & score1)

        lstDisplay.Items.Add(cmbHomeroom.Text)
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(cmbPlace.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: For the record, there is far more code there than is necessary and that makes it harder to address the issue. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and keep it in mind for future questions. If you need to create a simple test project in order to do that, that's what you do. You should often be doing just that as part of your own efforts to resolve an issue anyway. If you strip away all the noise and look at only what is specifically relevant to the issue, the solution is often staring you in the face but you just couldn't see it through the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by changing the select case

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
If rdbB25.Checked Or rdbF25.Checked Then
    Select Case cmbPlace.Text
        Case "1"
            place = 20
        Case "2"
            place = 10
        Case "3"
            place = 5
        Case "4"
            place = 4
        Case "5"
            place = 3
        Case "over 5"
            place = 1
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Place")
    End Select
End If
If rdbB50.Checked Or rdbF50.Checked Then
    Select Case cmbPlace.Text
        Case "1"
            place = 25
        Case "2"
            place = 15
        Case "3"
            place = 10
        Case "4"
            place = 6
        Case "5"
            place = 4
        Case "over 5"
            place = 2
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Place")
    End Select
End If



Select Case cmbHomeroom.Text
    Case "7.1"
        points1(intcounter1) = place
        intcounter1 = intcounter1 + 1
    Case "7.2"
        points2(intcounter2) = place
        intcounter2 = intcounter2 + 1
    Case "7.3"
        points3(intcounter3) = place
        intcounter3 = intcounter3 + 1
    Case "7.4"
        points4(intcounter4) = place
        intcounter4 = intcounter4 + 1
    Case "7.5"
        points5(intcounter5) = place
        intcounter5 = intcounter5 + 1
    Case "7.6"
        points6(intcounter6) = place
        intcounter6 = intcounter6 + 1
    Case "7.7"
        points7(intcounter7) = place
        intcounter7 = intcounter7 + 1
    Case "7.8"
        points8(intcounter8) = place
        intcounter8 = intcounter8 + 1
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a homeroom")
End Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Unfortunately this answer suffers from the same clutter as the question. It is probably a good solution, but there is no explanation as to what you changed or why it fixed the issue. A short description of the problem you identified and how you solved it would greatly improve this answer.